# mandar checkbox chequeados por metodo ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buenas tengo una encuesta con varias preguntas, para ser exacto son 100 y las respuestas son si y no, quisiera saber como puedo mandar las respuestas chequedas si o no a mi metodo ajax, mas bien lo que tengo duda es como mandarlo po la data para asi insertar en mi tabla de base de datos, ya e echo algo similar pero solo con 1 checkbox y en esta ocasion son 2 radio buttons, esto son mis radio buttons, al momento de, mandar a la base de datos solo existe una columna  que seria `respuesta_1` y ahi iria si chequeo si o si chequeo no

```
<td>
   <input id="radio_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="1">
       </td>
         si<td>
      no <input id="radio_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="0">
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias forma de hacer lo que quieres. La que propongo consiste en asociar cada número de pregunta con su respuesta (sí/no). Damos a cada radio nombres como estos: `si_1`, `no_1`. Por Javascript, al presionar el botón `Enviar` lanzamos un código que recorra todos los `radio`y guarde un array de los que están seleccionados. En nuestro código de ejemplo, en el que uso sólo tres preguntas por brevedad, el array se parecerá a esto:

```
["si_1","no_2","si_3"]
```

¡Ahí tenemos toda la información que se necesita! Podemos determinar que:

- Se respondió `sí` a la `Pregunta 1`
- Se respondió `no` a la `Pregunta 2`
- Se respondió `sí` a la `Pregunta 3`  ...

Veamos un ejemplo funcional:

```js
document.getElementById("btnEnviar").onclick = function() {
  var radioStatus = new Array();
  var allRadios = 
  document.querySelectorAll('input[class="radio"]').forEach(function(el) {

    if (el.checked) {
      radioStatus.push(el.id);
    }
  })

  var toPost = JSON.stringify(radioStatus);
  console.log(toPost);

};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Pregunta 1...</td>
    <td>
      sí <input id="si_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>no <input id="no_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pregunta 2...</td>
    <td>
      sí <input id="si_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>no <input id="no_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pregunta 3...</td>
    <td>
      sí <input id="si_3" type="radio" class="radio" name="r3" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>no <input id="no_3" type="radio" class="radio" name="r3" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Enviar/leer los datos

Los datos son guardados en la variable `toPost`, y los puedes enviar por Ajax al servidor. Nótese que se usa `JSON.stringify` para convertir el array en una cadena JSON y pueda ser más fácil de enviar/recuperar en el servidor.

En el parámetro `data` de Ajax puedes hacer algo así:

```
          data: { 'data' : toPost},
```

Y en PHP puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
if(isset($_POST["data")){
    $data=json_decode($_POST['data']);
    /*Trabajamos con $data*/
}
```

Ahora bien, los datos viene así:

- `si_1`
- `no_2`
- `si_3`

Pero yo necesito el `1`, el `2`, el `3`... para indentificar cada pregunta. ¡Ningún pánico! Esa información puede ser ampliamente aprovechada. Si en PHP haces un `explode` podrás obtener por separado los datos que necesitas para operar en la base de datos. Separarías por `_` y obtendrías entonces el número de cada pregunta y la pregunta que ésta recibió.

Ese trabajo de separación se puede hacer también desde el cliente, haciendo un `split` en Javascript y enviando al servidor un arreglo ya organizado con cada pregunta y su respuesta. Para este caso creo que sería más sencillo con `explode`.

Las otras etiquetas de los `radio`, como `value`, quedan *libres* para poder poner en ellas cualquier información que fuese necesaria eventualmente.

---

#### Otra posibilidad

Para simplificar el manejo del lado del servidor, puedes enviar un arreglo asociativo construido del lado del cliente.

En este ejemplo lo que se hace es meter en el array principal otro array con dos valores, uno será para el número de la pregunta y otro para la respuesta.

El array quedaría así:

```
[["1","si"],["2","no"],["3","si"]]
```

Haciéndolo así sería más fácil en el servidor obtener dos arrays por separado para usarlos en la inserción en la base de datos.

He aquí una prueba:

```js
document.getElementById("btnEnviar").onclick = function() {
  var radioId = "";
  var parts = "";
  var radioStatus = new Array();
  var allRadios =
    document.querySelectorAll('input[class="radio"]').forEach(function(el) {

      if (el.checked) {
        radioId = el.id;
        parts = radioId.split('_');
        radioStatus.push(new Array(parts[1], parts[0]));
      }
    })

  var toPost = JSON.stringify(radioStatus);
  console.log(toPost);

};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Pregunta 1...</td>
    <td>
      sí <input id="si_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>no <input id="no_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pregunta 2...</td>
    <td>
      sí <input id="si_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>no <input id="no_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pregunta 3...</td>
    <td>
      sí <input id="si_3" type="radio" class="radio" name="r3" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>no <input id="no_3" type="radio" class="radio" name="r3" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

También puedes producir esos dos arrays aquí mismo haciendo algo como:

var radioP = new Array();
  var radioR = new Array();

Y en el `each`:

```
    radioP.push((parts[1]);
    radioR.push((parts[0]);
```

Y luego mandas al servidor `radioP` y `radioR` como dos arrays independientes. Lo que pasa que esto renuncia a tener los datos estructurados y relacionados entre sí. Yo los mandaría como asociados y haría las separaciones necesarias, según las necesidades en el servidor.