# ayuda error :Column count doesn't match value count at row 1,

Tags: php

buenas tengo este error pero si tengo todos los campos, por que podría ser??

controlador

```
print_r(implode(',',(array)$_POST['data']));

        $data = implode(',',(array)$_POST['data']);

        $data = str_replace("[","",$data);
        $data = str_replace("]","",$data);
        $data = str_replace("\"", "'", $data);
        print_r($data);
        $this->model->insert($data);
```

Modelo

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO `tabla`(`form_avl_1`,`form_avl_2`,`form_avl_3`,
    `form_avl_4`,`form_avl_5`,`form_avl_6`,`form_avl_7`,`form_avl_8`,`form_avl_9`,`form_avl_10`,
    `form_avl_11`,`form_avl_12`,`form_avl_13`,`form_avl_14`,`form_avl_15`,`form_avl_16`,
    `form_avl_17`,`form_avl_18`,`form_avl_19`,`form_avl_20`,`form_avl_21`,`form_avl_22`,
    `form_avl_23`,`form_avl_24`,`form_avl_25`,`form_avl_26`,`form_avl_27`,`form_avl_28`,
    `form_avl_29`,`form_avl_30`,`form_avl_31`,`form_avl_32`,`form_avl_33`,`form_avl_34`,
    `form_avl_35`,`form_avl_36`,`form_avl_37`,`form_avl_38`,`form_avl_39`,`form_avl_40`,
    `form_avl_41`,`form_avl_42`,`form_avl_43`,`form_avl_44`,`form_avl_45`,`form_avl_46`,
    `form_avl_47`,`form_avl_48`,`form_avl_49`,`form_avl_50`,`form_avl_51`,`form_avl_52`,
    `form_avl_53`,`form_avl_54`,`form_avl_55`,`form_avl_56`,`form_avl_57`,`form_avl_58`,
    `form_avl_59`,`form_avl_60`,`form_avl_61`,`form_avl_62`,`form_avl_63`,`form_avl_64`,
    `form_avl_65`,`form_avl_66`,`form_avl_67`,`form_avl_68`,`form_avl_69`,`form_avl_70`,
    `form_avl_71`,`form_avl_72`,`form_avl_73`,`form_avl_74`,`form_avl_75`,`form_avl_76`,
    `form_avl_77`,`form_avl_78`,`form_avl_79`,`form_avl_80`,`form_avl_81`,`form_avl_82`,
    `form_avl_83`,`form_avl_84`,`form_avl_85`,`form_avl_86`,`form_avl_87`,`form_avl_88`,
    `form_avl_89`,`form_avl_90`,`form_avl_91`,`form_avl_92`,`form_avl_93`,`form_avl_94`,
    `form_avl_95`,`form_avl_96`,`form_avl_97`,`form_avl_98`,`form_avl_99`,`form_avl_100`,
    `form_avl_101`,`form_avl_102`,`form_avl_103`,`form_avl_104`,`form_avl_105`,`form_avl_106`,
    `form_avl_107`,`form_avl_108`,`form_avl_109`,`form_avl_110`)VALUES('".$data."');";

return $this->db->query($qry)->result();
```

imprime el error de base de datos (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1) pero no encuentro el error asi tal como lo puse lo hice separandolo para saber bien si me hace falta un campo pero no, el values es un array

```
INSERT INTO `prueba`.`tabla`(`form_avl_1`,`form_avl_2`,`form_avl_3`, `form_avl_4`,`form_avl_5`,`form_avl_6`,`form_avl_7`,`form_avl_8`,`form_avl_9`,`form_avl_10`, `form_avl_11`,`form_avl_12`,`form_avl_13`,`form_avl_14`,`form_avl_15`,`form_avl_16`, `form_avl_17`,`form_avl_18`,`form_avl_19`,`form_avl_20`,`form_avl_21`,`form_avl_22`, `form_avl_23`,`form_avl_24`,`form_avl_25`,`form_avl_26`,`form_avl_27`,`form_avl_28`, `form_avl_29`,`form_avl_30`,`form_avl_31`,`form_avl_32`,`form_avl_33`,`form_avl_34`, `form_avl_35`,`form_avl_36`,`form_avl_37`,`form_avl_38`,`form_avl_39`,`form_avl_40`, `form_avl_41`,`form_avl_42`,`form_avl_43`,`form_avl_44`,`form_avl_45`,`form_avl_46`, `form_avl_47`,`form_avl_48`,`form_avl_49`,`form_avl_50`,`form_avl_51`,`form_avl_52`, `form_avl_53`,`form_avl_54`,`form_avl_55`,`form_avl_56`,`form_avl_57`,`form_avl_58`, `form_avl_59`,`form_avl_60`,`form_avl_61`,`form_avl_62`,`form_avl_63`,`form_avl_64`, `form_avl_65`,`form_avl_66`,`form_avl_67`,`form_avl_68`,`form_avl_69`,`form_avl_70`, `form_avl_71`,`form_avl_72`,`form_avl_73`,`form_avl_74`,`form_avl_75`,`form_avl_76`, `form_avl_77`,`form_avl_78`,`form_avl_79`,`form_avl_80`,`form_avl_81`,`form_avl_82`, `form_avl_83`,`form_avl_84`,`form_avl_85`,`form_avl_86`,`form_avl_87`,`form_avl_88`, `form_avl_89`,`form_avl_90`,`form_avl_91`,`form_avl_92`,`form_avl_93`,`form_avl_94`, `form_avl_95`,`form_avl_96`,`form_avl_97`,`form_avl_98`,`form_avl_99`,`form_avl_100`, `form_avl_101`,`form_avl_102`,`form_avl_103`,`form_avl_104`,`form_avl_105`,`form_avl_106`, `form_avl_107`,`form_avl_108`,`form_avl_109`,`form_avl_110`)VALUES(
                                                '"si_1",        "si_2",     "si_3",         "si_4",     "si_5",     "si_6",     "si_7",     "si_8",         "si_9",     "si_10",        "si_11",        "si_12",    "si_13",    "si_14",        "si_15",    "si_16",        "si_17",        "si_18",    "si_19",    "si_20",        "si_21",    "si_22",        "si_23",        "si_24",    "si_25",    "si_26",        "si_27",        "si_28",        "si_29"     ,"si_30",   "si_31",        "si_32",        "si_33",    "si_34",        "si_35",    "si_36",        "si_37",    "si_38",        "si_39",    "si_40",        "si_41",        "si_42",    "si_43",    "si_44",        "si_45",        "si_46",    "si_47",        "si_48",    "si_49",        "si_50",    "si_51",        "si_52",        "si_53",    "si_54",        "si_55",    "si_56",        "si_57",    "si_58",    "si_59",        "si_60"         ,"si_61",       "si_62",    "si_63",        "si_64",    "si_65",        "si_66",        "si_67"     ,"si_68",   "si_69",        "si_70",        "si_71",    "si_72",        "si_73",    "si_74",        "si_75",    "si_76",        "si_77",    "si_78",        "si_79",    "si_80",        "si_81",        "si_82",    "si_83",        "si_84",    "si_85",        "si_86",    "si_87",        "si_88",    "si_89",        "si_90",        "si_91",    "si_92",    "si_93",    "si_94",        "si_95",        "si_96",        "si_97",    "si_98",        "si_99",    "si_100",       "si_101",       "si_102",       "si_103",   "si_104",       "si_105",       "si_106",       "si_107",       "si_108",   "si_109",       "si_110"');
```

Aqui empieza mi print del data  `["si_1","si_2","si_3","si_4","si_5","si_6","si_7","si_8","si_9","si_10","si_11","si_12","si_13","si_14","si_15","si_16","si_17","si_18","si_19","si_20","si_21","si_22","si_23","si_24","si_25","si_26","si_27","si_28","si_29","si_30","si_31","si_32","si_33","si_34","si_35","si_36","si_37","si_38","si_39","si_40","si_41","si_42","si_43","si_44","si_45","si_46","si_47","si_48","si_49","si_50","si_51","si_52","si_53","si_54","si_55","si_56","si_57","si_58","si_59","si_60","si_61","si_62","si_63","si_64","si_65","si_66","si_67","si_68","si_69","si_70","si_71","si_72","si_73","si_74","si_75","si_76","si_77","si_78","si_79","si_80","si_81","si_82","si_83","si_84","si_85","si_86","si_87","si_88","si_89","si_90","si_91","si_92","si_93","si_94","si_95","si_96","si_97","si_98","si_99","si_100","si_101","si_102","si_103","si_104","si_105","si_106","si_107","si_108","si_109","si_110"]`

esto contiene mi data

Este es mi nuevo data quitandole los [] y las "" reemplazandolas por ', ya no me marca el error de antes ahora solo me dice error sintaxis en linea 21

```
'si_1','si_2','si_3','si_4','si_5','si_6','si_7','si_8','si_9','si_10','si_11','si_12','si_13','si_14','si_15','si_16','si_17','si_18','si_19','si_20','si_21','si_22','si_23','si_24','si_25','si_26','si_27','si_28','si_29','si_30','si_31','si_32','si_33','si_34','si_35','si_36','si_37','si_38','si_39','si_40','si_41','si_42','si_43','si_44','si_45','si_46','si_47','si_48','si_49','si_50','si_51','si_52','si_53','si_54','si_55','si_56','si_57','si_58','si_59','si_60','si_61','si_62','si_63','si_64','si_65','si_66','si_67','si_68','si_69','si_70','si_71','si_72','si_73','si_74','si_75','si_76','si_77','si_78','si_79','si_80','si_81','si_82','si_83','si_84','si_85','si_86','si_87','si_88','si_89','si_90','si_91','si_92','si_93','si_94','si_95','si_96','si_97','si_98','si_99','si_100','si_101','si_102','si_103','si_104','si_105','si_106','si_107','si_108','si_109','si_110'
```

Comment: Podrías imprimir el valor de .$data. para saber que es lo que trae?

Comment: Por favor di lo que intentas hacer. Da la impresión de que quieres hacer algo sencillo escogiendo un camino bastante complicado. No sé a que se deben manipulaciones tan extrañas como esta: `$data = str_replace("[","",$data);
        $data = str_replace("]","",$data);`  ¿quizá ignoras que hay en PHP miles de funciones para casi todo? Y si no existen no hay problema, se pueden inventar. Sería de gran ayuda que explicaras un poco lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: es algo sencillo que no e encontrado la solución, en el controlador puse eso porque como es un array y al momento de hacer el insert toma los [] y ya con eso se los quito para que realize el insert, pense q eera por eso que me marcaba el error pero no sigue igual

Comment: eso último que pusiste es tu print_r de data o qué es?

Comment: si, ya lo modifique, ok entonces ya hasta ahorita, copie y pegue eso en mi base de datos y marca el error, entonces lo q hice fue quitar las "" y sustituirlas por ' y ya no me marco el error sino un error de sintaxis

Comment: ok, ya pude lo que hice fue:
1.- en vez de ' ".$data." ' lo cambie a ".$data."//por defaul ya trae las comillas el array.
2.- quitar el result() porque es un insert y ya funciono

Comment: Cuando vi los datos que hay en el arreglo, supe que este código tenía relación [con esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/206650/29967). Y como sosprechaba, te estás complicando la existencia. Creo que lo que quieres es sacar aparte cada dato: la respuesta (`sí` o `no`) y el número de la pregunta. Entonces sólo tienes que recorrer tu array **tal cual, sin manipularlo**, haciendo explode de cada fila. Por ejemplo: **`foreach ($data as $row){$parts=explode("_",$row); $r=$parts[0]; $p=$parts[1]; echo "Pregunta: $p .... Respuesta: $r".PHP_EOL;}`** Ahí te imprimirá cada parte...

Comment: Para la inserción conviene que uses consultas preparadas. Con mysqli o PDO podrías construir un `INSERT` dinámico, usando los valores que vienen organizados en el array y haciendo el `explode`  como he explicado. En ese `INSERT` dinámico que completarías también dentro del `foreach` usarías el valor de `$p` para añadirlo a `form_avl_` y el código sería automático, dinámico y seguro.

Answer (score 0):

Olvida todo el código de arriba.

Si data es un array con datos como estos: `"[si_1","si_2","si_3","si_4","si_5", ...]` aquí lo interesante sería crear un código dinámico. Observa qué fácil:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO `tabla` ";
$pre="`form_avl_";
$vals=array();
$cols=array();

foreach ($data as $row){
    $parts=explode("_",$row);
    $vals[]=$parts[0];
    $cols[]=$pre.$parts[1]."`";
}
$qryCols= implode(', ' , $cols);
$qryVals= implode(', ' , $vals);
$qry .=$qryCols.$qryVals;

/*Probemos como quedó :)*/
echo $qry;

/*Ejecutamos*/
return $this->db->query($qry)->result();
```

> **NOTAS:**
>
> - Esta consulta es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Conviene que uses consultas preparadas para prevenirlo.
> - Tomando en cuenta que los datos vienen [de esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/206650/29967), el código en el servidor se podría simplificar si los datos viniesen
>     asociados de otra forma, pero perfectamente sincronizados. Podemos
>     pensar por ejemplo en dos arrays o en un array asociativo
>     respuesta/pregunta que se pudieran diferenciar con una sólo línea de
>     código y hacer un `implode` directo sobre cada uno de ellos.