# Exporta a Excel usuarios seleccionados a través de un checkbok php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Estoy intentando hacer algo que nunca he visto y no se si es posible.
En un listado que traigo de la base de datos, tengo un checkbok en cada uno con su respectivos id, lo que quiero es exportar a Excel solamente los usuarios seleccionados.

Mi código index.php que contiene el listado.

```
<?php
include("conectar.ini.php");
        
$sql = "SELECT id_personal , apellido, nombre FROM personal";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th><th>Select</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id_personal"]. "</td><td>" . $row["apellido"] . "</td><td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='export[]' value='".$row["id_personal"]."'></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo "<a href='excelprueba.php'>Export to Excel</a>";
?>
```

y ese el el archivo excelprueba.php que intento capturar los usuarios seleccionados.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
    header('Content-type:application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=LISTADO PERSONAL VIAJE.xls');
    require_once('conectar.ini.php');

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    foreach($_POST["export"] as $user){
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT id_personal , apellido, nombre FROM personal where id_personal = $user");
    }
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
<table width="90%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ADD3F3" style="text-align: center">Id</td>
<td bgcolor="#ADD3F3" style="text-align: center">Apellido</td>
<td bgcolor="#ADD3F3" style="text-align: center">Nombre</td>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

He intentado con un foreach pero no funciona, ¿Alquilen sabe si se puede y en donde estoy equivocándome?

Ya he hecho varios Excel en php pero nunca con un checkbox.

Comment: Esto sería muy fácil de hacer si usas Ajax. Puedes tener un botón, le asignas un evento de escucha de modo que cuando se haga click en ese botón recojas todos los que estén seleccionados y los envías al servidor vía Ajax y allí construyes tu Excel en base a esos datos.

Comment: Para que tengas una idea, [sería algo parecido a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/206650/29967). El código muestra cómo recopilar todos los seleccionados y mandarlos al servidor vía Ajax.

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder, ya pude resolver sin Ajax, con el mismo php

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurren  varios caminos:
1.- un formulario, cada ckeck es un input , cada dato  de usuario es un campo readonly,
lo recibes en el server y procesas para crear el excell.
2.- usar un form que envie los ID como un array y realices consulta de solo lo que que desas, con esto procesar el archivo a excell
3. usar javascript que recorra la tabla que creaste y solo agregue los check al excell
NOTA: 1 y 2 lo se hacer, el 3 no pero no creo que sea dificil

Comment: Ya lo hice con php, Gracias